# How to assign the width of plotly graph based on the column width?

Tags: r, plotly, shinydashboard

I have a plotly chart on a shiny app. Currently, its located in the middle of the screen under a 4 sized column. the issue here is that the fixed size of the plotly element overrides the column width, so when i resize the screen, the graph will remain size fixed.

In addition, the graph is leaving a lot of space below it (please see the horizontal line at the end). How can i remove that space?

[image]

UI

```
      fluidRow(
        #valueBoxOutput("prescripciones_covid"),
        column(4, 
               offset = 4,
               plotlyOutput('plot1')   
      
      )),
          fluidRow(
            hr(style = "border-top: 1px solid #000000;"))
```

SERVER

```
output$plot1 <- renderPlotly(
    plot1 <- plot_ly( a ,
                      labels = ~DxPpal, 
                      values = ~n,
                      type = 'pie',
                      width = 390,
                      height = 250,
                      #text = ~DxPpal,
                      hovertemplate = "%{label} <br> %{percent}<br> %{value} ") %>%
      layout( title = list  ( text = "Top 10 Diagnosticos"),
              font = list (size = 11) ) %>% 
      layout(legend = list(orientation = 'h')) %>%
      layout(autosize = F,  margin = list(l = 0,
                                          r = 0,
                                          b = 5,
                                          t = 30))  %>%
       layout(showlegend = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
fluidRow(
  #valueBoxOutput("prescripciones_covid"),
  column(4, 
         offset = 4,
         div(plotlyOutput('plot1', width="100%"), align = "center")   
         
  ))
```

Edit: UI Example

```
tabPanel(
  fluidRow(
    column(width=4, div(valueBoxOutput("first_vb", width = 10), align = "center")),
    column(width=4, div(valueBoxOutput("second_vb", width = 10), align = "center")),
    column(width=4, div(valueBoxOutput("third_vb", width = 10), align = "center"))
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(width=4, offset = 4, div(valueBoxOutput("fourth_vb", width = 10), align = "center")
  ),
  br(),
  div(plotlyOuput("plot1", width = "50%", height= 450), align = "center"),
  br(),
  hr()
)
```

Comment: thanks. do i still need to keep the size parameters on the sever side?. also, can you please check my edited question with an addendum

Comment: no you can remove the width on the server side. You can also move the height to the ui side. Regarding your horizontal lines, its because you have another fluid row after the plot fluid row. What is in there? If its just the `hr()` you can put it outside the `fluidRow()` and remove the `fluidRow()`

Comment: thanks. the height also helped to understand my second part of the question

Comment: Ive added in a UI example of what would make things align well. Feel free to play around with the plotly height and width

Comment: your suggestions are working great. im having one minor issue: the first time i press on a "Process" button than triggers a `observeEvent(input$prescripciones_gobutton1`, the graph is built correctly according to the window size. if i press the button again, the graph rebuils in a bigger size. a workaround is to either resize the window or reload the entire app. do you know how could i fix this?

Comment: This shouldnt happen. Do you have width/height dimensions in the server side of the plotly? Also can you elaborate on what happens inside the `observeEvent`?

Comment: yes, please see this question for context. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67910687/how-to-automatically-resize-a-plotly-graph-with-every-button-press